# Codeigniter Force download files

Tags: php, codeigniter

By going through the Codeigniter documentation, I am using the following code to force download files from my server.

```
function download($file_id){
        $file = $this->uploadmodel->getById($file_id); //getting all the file details
                                                      //for $file_id (all details are stored in DB)
        $data = file_get_contents($file->full_path); // Read the file's contents
        $name = $file->file_name;;

        force_download($name, $data);
    }
```

The code is working file for images, but when it comes with the case of PDF files, it is not working. I have not tested it for all file extensions, but since it is not working for PDF, it might not work for other various file types.
Any solution?

Comment: Not working how? doesn't download? doesn't open in a PDF reader? errors?

Comment: yea.. when I clink on the link that I have created `download/32` , it just opens the link and it is a blank page.
 it is `download/$file_id` ..

Comment: .zip, .jpg, .txt, .gif all are working, but not .pdf

Comment: check your server's error log or in a file called error_log inside the app folder you might find some helpful info there. if neither helps, try a different browser or try clearing the cache of your current browser.

Comment: when you try to download pdf's can you print what is the array you are getting to $file..

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've had similar problems. I think the problem resides in certain mime's and headers sent to the browser(s). I've end up using the code I found here <strike>http://taggedzi.com/articles/display/forcing-downloads-through-codeigniter</strike>. Use the function below instead of force_download. It has worked for me so far.

```
    function _push_file($path, $name)
    {
      // make sure it's a file before doing anything!
      if(is_file($path))
      {
        // required for IE
        if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression')) { ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off'); }

        // get the file mime type using the file extension
        $this->load->helper('file');

        $mime = get_mime_by_extension($path);

        // Build the headers to push out the file properly.
        header('Pragma: public');     // required
        header('Expires: 0');         // no cache
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate ('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime ($path)).' GMT');
        header('Cache-Control: private',false);
        header('Content-Type: '.$mime);  // Add the mime type from Code igniter.
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($name).'"');  // Add the file name
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Content-Length: '.filesize($path)); // provide file size
        header('Connection: close');
        readfile($path); // push it out
        exit();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Maybe this was a problem with the older versions of codeigniter, but now that I am using codeigniter 2.2, pdf does not have problem, and RJ Anoop's answer was useful.

Comment: @Carlos The embedded URL http://taggedzi.com/articles/display/forcing-downloads-through-codeigniter no longer exists, it's a 404. Edit: I striked it out in an edit.

Answer (score 10):

It is working for `.pdf`s also.
Check the path to the file - that might be the problem.
I, too, had that problem, but when I corrected the path to the file, it worked perfectly.
The following is how I wrote the code:

```
if($src ==  "xyyx")
{
$pth    =   file_get_contents(base_url()."path/to/the/file.pdf");
$nme    =   "sample_file.pdf";
force_download($nme, $pth);     
}
```

Comment: Wasn't working initially. just showing a blank page. I forgort to add the ".pdf" extension

Comment: im getting `failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden `

Comment: This is not a problem with the script, but with the resource you are requesting. The web server is returning the "forbidden" status code.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, I think its best practice for that problem.

```
function download($file_id)
{
        $this->load->helper('file'); // Load file helper
        $file = $this->uploadmodel->getById($file_id); //Get file by id
        $data = read_file($file->full_path); // Use file helper to read the file's
        $name = $file->file_name;;

        force_download($name, $data);
}
```

Comment: Just add the $this->load->helper('download'); to load helper functions for download files