# Download csv from codeigniter mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, csv

I think I'm missing something obvious. I'm trying to export a dataset from a MySQL query to CSV without printing it to the browser.

Here's my code:

```
<?php

$this->load->helper('download');
$list = $stories;
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

$data = file_get_contents('php://output'); // Read the file's contents
$name = 'data.csv';
force_download($name, $data);
fclose($fp);

?>
```

`$stories` is my array created from the MySQL query.

Currently everything prints to the browser with no errors and no download but I would like to force a CSV download. How can I do this?

---

final working code:

```
 $this->load->helper('download');

    $list = $stories;
    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    foreach ($list as $fields) {
        fputcsv($fp, $fields);
        }

    $data = file_get_contents('php://output'); 
    $name = 'data.csv';

    // Build the headers to push out the file properly.
    header('Pragma: public');     // required
    header('Expires: 0');         // no cache
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Cache-Control: private',false);
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($name).'"');  // Add the file name
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Connection: close');
    exit();

    force_download($name, $data);
    fclose($fp);
```

Comment: You need to output an Header for force download (i think it's the best way)

Comment: thanks, i did try this but the csv that downloads contains my html rather than the data from the database. i am using this additional code `header('Content-type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="data.csv"');`

Comment: Have you make a right csv file? When you open it into browser it allow you to save it to your desktop?

Comment: yes saving the file to desktop but the csv file i download is full of html not the database query

Comment: how you have created the file?

Comment: sorry. i dont understand? the code above generates the file

Comment: That's probably because the file is malformed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't tell what headers are set from the Codeigniter `force_download()` function sets. If it is indeed going to the screen I would suspect the necessary headers are missing. You can add the below headers to your code to set correct csv dowload headers (The cache control will ensure fresh data download each time:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$name);
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
```

Comment: i added this code and removed the old duplicates and now i get a blank csv?

Comment: You may not be streaming the data back out. This can be done with a simple `echo $data`

Comment: hmmm still giving me a blank file. I have updated my code above to show you what I am doing in case I am making a dumb error

Comment: after searching some more on the basis of your advice I found [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14835671/codeigniter-force-download-files/14839153#14839153). I stole the code and everything works - see above.

Answer (score 17):

You can call model `CSV()` from your controller as

```
$this->load->model('Users_model');
$this->Users_model->csv();
```

and in the model

```
function csv()
{
        $this->load->dbutil();
        $this->load->helper('file');
        $this->load->helper('download');
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM Users");
        $delimiter = ",";
        $newline = "\r\n";
        $data = $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($query, $delimiter, $newline);
        force_download('CSV_Report.csv', $data);
}
```

Your File will start downloading

Answer (score 2):

i am use this and its work

```
  header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=backup" . date('y-m-d') . ".csv");
            header('Last-Modified: ' . date('D M j G:i:s T Y'));
            $outss = fopen("php://output", "w");
            $this->db->order_by('ID', 'DESC');
            $query = $this->db->get('urls');
            foreach ($query->result_array() as $rows) {
                fputcsv($outss, $rows);
            }
            fclose($outss);
            return;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to generate reports in csv format then it will quite easy with codeigniter.

**Place this code in your Controller**

```
function get_report()
{
    $this->load->model('Main_Model');
    $this->load->dbutil();
    $this->load->helper('file');
    /* get the object   */
    $report = $this->Main_Model->print_report();
    $delimiter = ",";
    $newline = "\r\n";
    $new_report = $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($report, $delimiter, $newline);
    write_file( 'application/third_party/file.csv', $new_report);
    $this->load->view('report_success.php');
}
```

---

**Put this code into Model**

```
public function print_report()
{
    return $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM Table_name");
}
```

---

`report_success.php` is just Successful Notification.

Your Report is being Exported. Thank you

---

Finally Your "file.csv" is generated.
its basically stored at physical storage.
In `CodeIgniter/application/third-party/file.csv`

---

it works.
it will help you.

Comment: How can i get directly download in the browser instead of stored in the desired location?

Answer (score 0):

**Here we have sample result set from MySQL and want to export in CSV file.**

**Step 1: Get MySql data in key value pair.**

```
$data = array(
         '0' => array('Name'=> 'Parvez', 'Status' =>'complete', 'Priority'=>'Low', 'Salary'=>'001'),
         '1' => array('Name'=> 'Alam', 'Status' =>'inprogress', 'Priority'=>'Low', 'Salary'=>'111'),
         '2' => array('Name'=> 'Sunnay', 'Status' =>'hold', 'Priority'=>'Low', 'Salary'=>'333'),
         '3' => array('Name'=> 'Amir', 'Status' =>'pending', 'Priority'=>'Low', 'Salary'=>'444'),
         '4' => array('Name'=> 'Amir1', 'Status' =>'pending', 'Priority'=>'Low', 'Salary'=>'777'),
         '5' => array('Name'=> 'Amir2', 'Status' =>'pending', 'Priority'=>'Low', 'Salary'=>'777')
        );
```

**Step 2: PHP code to get options type and force to browser download file instead of display.**

```
if(isset($_POST["ExportType"]))
```

{

```
switch($_POST["ExportType"])
{
    case "export-to-csv" :
        // Submission from
        $filename = $_POST["ExportType"] . ".csv";       
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Content-type: text/csv");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
        ExportCSVFile($data);
        //$_POST["ExportType"] = '';
        exit();
    default :
        die("Unknown action : ".$_POST["action"]);
        break;
}
```

}

```
function ExportCSVFile($records) {
    // create a file pointer connected to the output stream
    $fh = fopen( 'php://output', 'w' );
    $heading = false;
        if(!empty($records))
          foreach($records as $row) {
            if(!$heading) {
              // output the column headings
              fputcsv($fh, array_keys($row));
              $heading = true;
            }
            // loop over the rows, outputting them
             fputcsv($fh, array_values($row));

          }
          fclose($fh);
}
```

**Step 3: Define html layout for display data in table and button to fire export-to-csv action.**

```
<div><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="export-to-csv">Export to csv</a></div>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post" id="export-form">
                    <input type="hidden" value='' id='hidden-type' name='ExportType'/>
                  </form>
              <table id="" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Priority</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
              </tr>
            <tbody>
              <?php foreach($data as $row):?>
              <tr>
              <td><?php echo $row ['Name']?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row ['Status']?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row ['Priority']?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row ['Salary']?></td>
              </tr>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

**Step 3: Now we will use jQuery code to get click event.**

```
 <script  type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#export-to-csv').bind("click", function() {
var target = $(this).attr('id');
switch(target) {
    case 'export-to-csv' :
    $('#hidden-type').val(target);
    //alert($('#hidden-type').val());
    $('#export-form').submit();
    $('#hidden-type').val('');
    break
}
});
    });
</script>
```