# How to export CSV file in code igniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

We need to export(Download) CSV file in Code igniter. This will be export my table data only and how can i change formate of my csv file? please any one help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download csv from codeigniter mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20840274/download-csv-from-codeigniter-mysql)

Answer (score 6):

Codeigniter has a built in class for this. Try this:

```
$this->load->dbutil();
$this->load->helper('file');
$this->load->helper('download');
$query = $this->db->query("Your SQL Here");
$delimiter = ",";
$newline = "\r\n";
$data = $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($query, $delimiter, $newline);
force_download('CSV_Report.csv', $data);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can see for here how to export database result into CSV file

http://www.code2learn.com/2012/03/generating-csv-file-using-codeigniter.html

or you can create helper with this code

```
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

if ( ! function_exists('array_to_csv'))
{
    function array_to_csv($array, $download = "")
    {
        if ($download != "")
        {    
            header('Content-Type: application/csv');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachement; filename="' . $download . '"');
        }        

        ob_start();
        $f = fopen($download, 'wb') or show_error("Can't open php://output");
        $n = 0;        
        foreach ($array as $line)
        {
            $n++;
            if ( ! fputcsv($f, $line))
            {
                show_error("Can't write line $n: $line");
            }
        }
        fclose($f) or show_error("Can't close php://output");
        $str = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        if ($download == "")
        {
            return $str;    
        }
        else
        {    
            echo $str;
        }        
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists('query_to_csv'))
{
    function query_to_csv($query, $headers = TRUE, $download = "")
    {
        if ( ! is_object($query) OR ! method_exists($query, 'list_fields'))
        {
            show_error('invalid query');
        }

        $array = array();

        if ($headers)
        {
            $line = array();
            foreach ($query->list_fields() as $name)
            {
                $line[] = $name;
            }
            $array[] = $line;
        }

        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
        {
            $line = array();
            foreach ($row as $item)
            {
                $line[] = $item;
            }
            $array[] = $line;
        }

        echo array_to_csv($array, $download);
    }
}

/* End of file csv_helper.php */
/* Location: ./system/helpers/csv_helper.php */
```

And then your controller function look like this

```
function create_csv(){
$this->load->helper('url');
                $this->load->helper('csv');

            $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM <tablename>');
            $num = $query->num_fields();
            $var =array();
            $i=1;
            $fname="";
            while($i <= $num){
                $test = $i;
                $value = $this->input->post($test);

                if($value != ''){
                        $fname= $fname." ".$value;
                        array_push($var, $value);

                    }
                 $i++;
            }

            $fname = trim($fname);

            $fname=str_replace(' ', ',', $fname);

            $this->db->select($fname);
            $quer = $this->db->get('<tablename>');

            query_to_csv($quer,TRUE,'Products_'.date('dMy').'.csv');

        }
}
```