# Download file helper

Tags: php, codeigniter, download, helper

I wanna download my file that i have upload to my web
Im just saving the name of the file to database

My controller

```
public function index()
{   
    $data['file'] = $this->home_model->file();
    $this->load->view('file', $data);
}

public function download()
{   

    $id_file = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $data = file_get_contents("/upload/kepsek/".$id_file);
    force_download('$id_file', $data);
}
```

My model

```
function file()
    {
        $query=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM silabus");
        return $query->result();

    }
```

My view

```
<table class="table table-bordered text-center" id="table-user">
                    <thead>
                      <tr class="info">
                        <th>Download</th>
                        <th>Pelajaran</th>

                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <?php
                      foreach($file as $data){
                      ?>
                      <tr>
                        <td width="50%"><a href="<?php echo site_url('download/download/'.$data->file);?>">Download</a></td>
                        <td width="50%"><?php echo $data->pelajaran;?></td>
                        </tr>
                      <?php
                      }
                      ?>
                      </tbody>
                      <tfoot>
                      </tfoot>
                  </table>
```

When i click download nothing happend
Its there any way to make it work?

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14835671/codeigniter-force-download-files and try using `_push_file` instead of `force_download`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$data = file_get_contents("upload/kepsek/".$id_file);
```

and also check the "upload/kepsek/".$id_file file exist or not

Answer (score 0):

```
<table class="table table-bordered text-center" id="table-user">
    <thead>
    <tr class="info">
        <th>Download</th>
        <th>Pelajaran</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
        foreach($file as $data){
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td width="50%"><a href="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/download/download/'.$data['file'];?>">Download</a></td>
                <td width="50%"><?php echo $data->pelajaran;?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php
        }
    ?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Then in Download Controller

```
public function index()
{   
    $data['file'] = $this->home_model->get_file();
    $this->load->view('file', $data);
}

public function download($id)
{   
    $this->load->helper('file');
    $this->load->helper('download');

    $data = file_get_contents("./upload/kepsek/".$id);  //check file exist
    $name = my_file.php//your file type
    force_download($data, $name);
}
```

In model

```
function get_file()
{
    $query= $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM silabus");
    $result =  $query->result_array();
    return $result;
}
```