# How can i setting utf-8 to csv file in php [codeigniter]

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter, utf-8, export-to-csv

```
public function ExportCSV(){
    $this->load->dbutil();
    $this->load->helper('file');
    $this->load->helper('download');        
    $delimiter = ",";
    $newline = "\r\n";
    $slash = "∕";
    $filename = "testnaja.csv";
    $query = "select * from student where room_id = 011";
    $result = $this->db->query($query);
    $data = $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($result, $delimiter, $newline);               
    force_download($filename, $data);
}
```

I want to generate excel file exporting data from my table to it.
The output in .xls and .csv

In csv output is:

[image]

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your force_download from

```
force_download($filename, $data);
```

To this:

```
force_download($filename, "\xEF\xBB\xBF" . $data);
```

which makes the output UTF-8 + BOM so it's recognized by MS Excel

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I understood you correctly, but if your problem is that you'd like Excel to recognize your CSV file as being UTF-8 encoded, you'll have to add a UTF-8 [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) to your file. Just prepend your CSV output with

```
chr(239) . chr(187) . chr(191) // xEF xBB xBF
```

For example:

```
$data = chr(239) . chr(187) . chr(191) . $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($result, $delimiter, $newline);
```

If your problem is about forcing a download, perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/a/33593363/11354 is going to help.

Answer (score 0):

To setup codeigniter to download CSV format, use the following code.

```
function _push_file($path, $name)
{
  // make sure it's a file before doing anything!
  if(is_file($path))
  {
    // required for IE
    if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression')) { ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off'); }

    // get the file mime type using the file extension
    $this->load->helper('file');

    $mime = get_mime_by_extension($path);

    // Build the headers to push out the file properly.
    header('Pragma: public');     // required
    header('Expires: 0');         // no cache
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate ('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime ($path)).' GMT');
    header('Cache-Control: private',false);
    header('Content-Type: '.$mime);  // Add the mime type from Code igniter.
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($name).'"');  // Add the file name
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($path)); // provide file size
    header('Connection: close');
    readfile($path); // push it out
    exit();
}
```

Duplicate from : [Codeigniter Force download files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14835671/codeigniter-force-download-files/14839153#14839153)

and also from : [Download csv from codeigniter mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20840274/download-csv-from-codeigniter-mysql)