# I need to add pagination to this page as I am getting a set of elements dynamically from db

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgnier I am uploading  a file into db now on button click I want the file to be downloaded in the front end.

Comment: Title is `X` and description is `Y`, Please share your code and try.

Comment: It is simple I have uploaded a pdf file using my back end tool now I want the file to be downloaded using a download button in the front end

Comment: refer this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14835671/codeigniter-force-download-files

Answer (score 0):

According to your question in description, you can download the existing file available on the server with the help of **codeigniter** download helper as follows -:

```
$this->load->helper('download');
$data = file_get_contents("/path/to/photo.jpg"); // Read the file's contents
$name = 'myphoto.jpg';
force_download($name, $data);
```